# How do I keep track of the endpoints being hit for a request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging

I am a newbie Web/Rails developer. The codebase(uses multiple docker containers) that I have been provided with is quite vast and when I am assigned issues to solve, it is difficult to understand exactly which end points are being hit with every request.  Is there a simpler way to do this ? Something that just prints out the methods and the views being rendered

I generally skim through the docker logs/rails log to get an idea but it can be very time consuming.

Comment: You can go through application server logs. Maybe `grep` appropriately

Comment: If you're looking for a quick hint and vaguely what's being rendered, then you can look at the log. But beyond that, there's not much more you can do besides `grep` (search for clues), learn how the application has been architectured through experience, or simply read the code and trace it through.

Comment: I mean... *"Something that just prints out the methods and the views being rendered"* -- this is literally what the log does. If it's logging insufficient information for you, then you can try tweaking the settings.

Comment: You can also look into using third party tools such as [newrelic](https://newrelic.com/), but to be honest StackOverflow isn't an appropriate forum for promoting third party software like this.